# How to determine which application/service is constantly using the hard drive?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I want to know what program is responsible for the constant activity of my hard drive. I have `Process Explorer`, `Process Monitor`, `Filemon`, and `Regmon` running, but I am still not able to detect what is using my hard drive.

Is this even possible to detect? Something tells me not.

Comment: We'll need more details. What operating system? What hardware? When did the problem start?

Comment: Windows XP SP2, Intel Centrino Duo T2400 1.83Ghz, 1GB Ram, Nvidia Go 7400, problem started like this week i think. Hard drive starts loading every 10 - 15 seconds. Tried DiskMon but all it does is shows activity and not a single clue to what file is being used... What a useless crap.

Comment: What is wrong with Process Monitor? Leave it running for a while and then look at the file Events columns under Tools/ Process Activity summary.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, you can use Resource Monitor (type `perfmon /res` into the Start menu search box). Look at the Disk tab and sort by "Total (B/sec)".

Comment: Instead of `perfmon /res`, can also just type `resmon`.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896653) from time to time to get more data about the running processes, such as how much I/O each process is performing.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure if it's available in Windows XP)

Start `perfmon.exe` and look for anything that has to with I/O or the hard drive. (In Windows 7 you can see data for every single process there)